# Referência entre duas tabelas pelo HeidiSQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, mariadb

Amigos, estou usando o HeidiSQL é tenho um banco de dados: MariaDB criei duas tabelas e quero referenciar id da tabela cliente, com user_id da tabela posts.
E eu esqueci como fazer referência, usando o aplicativo acima, esqueci por um problema sério de DNA.

Comment: E o que você quer?

Comment: @weltonvaz você está referindo a criar um join ?

Comment: Eu quero fazer referência entre o campo user_id da tabela post, com a (chave primaria) id da tabela usuários.

Comment: @Edvaldo Lucena na realidade eu quero usar comando Inner Join no HeidiSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim: Acesse a instância o qual está seu banco de dados e clique em arquivo > Nova aba para consulta e digite seu select .

```
select Tabela.coluna from post 
   inner join usuarios 
   on post.user_id = usuarios.id
```

Comment: Programaticamente eu sei fazer eu quero fazer no HeidiSQL

Comment: Acesse a instância o qual está seu banco de dados e clique em arquivo > Nova aba para consulta e digite seu select .

Comment: Valeu obrigado, era isso que não lembrava

Comment: @weltonvaz por favor marque a resposta que solucionou sua dúvida.

Comment: Marcado, muito obrigado pela atenção.